# Filter on associations' ids with ElasticSearch and Tire

Tags: activerecord, elasticsearch, tire

I've been hurting my head against what should be a simple query for quite a while now. I looked at all the documentation and examples, as well as most questions regarding `Tire` here on StackOverflow with no success.

Basically, I'm trying to filter my search results based on the IDs of some associated models.

Here's the model (note that I still use dynamic mapping at the moment):

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  # also has a string attribute named 'kind'
end
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter my search query by the `city_id`, by one `tag_id` and by `kind`.

I've tried building the query, but I only get errors because I can't seem to build it correctly. Here's what I have so far (not working):

```
Location.search do
  query { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
  filter :term, { city_id: params[:city_id] } if params[:city_id].present? # I'd like to use the ids filter, but have no idea of the syntax I'm supposed to use
  filter :ids, { 'tag.id', values: [params[:tag_id]] } if params[:tag_id].present? # does not compile
  filter :match, { kind: params[:kind] } if params[:kind].present? # does not compile either
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the dynamic mapping doesn't cut it for this kind of scenario. I also had to define how my data was indexed.

Here's my mapping:

```
mapping do
  indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :kind, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :city_id, index: :not_analyzed
  indexes :tags do
    indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
  end
end
```

and my custom `to_indexed_json`:

```
def to_indexed_json
  {
    kind: kind,
    city_id: city_id,
    tags: tags.map do |t|
      {
        id: t.id
      }
    end
  }.to_json
end
```

Finally, I can filter like so:

```
  Location.search do
    query { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
    filter :term, { city_id: params[:city_id] } if params[:city_id].present?
    filter :term, { "tags.id" => params[:tag_id] } if params[:tag_id].present?
    filter :term, { kind: params[:kind] } if params[:kind].present?
  end
```

The important part is the tags indexing which allows me to use `"tags.id"` in a filter.

Comment: That's correct. BTW, if you're not using faceted navigation, you should use a `filtered` query, not top-level `filter`.

Comment: @karmi what's the difference? Also, I might eventually add facets, this is only a work in progress.